# Error on loading account with qiskit: "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'"

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

We are using an open account.
We can not load the account even when we use the code on new notebook.
The error message is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-217ef0eaf621> in <module>
      6 from qiskit.visualization import *
      7 # Loading your IBM Q account(s)
----> 8 provider = IBMQ.load_account()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqfactory.py in load_account(self)
    152 
    153         # Check for valid credentials.
--> 154         credentials_list = list(discover_credentials().values())
    155 
    156         if not credentials_list:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/credentials/__init__.py in discover_credentials(qiskitrc_filename)
     61     for display_name, (reader_function, kwargs) in readers.items():
     62         try:
---> 63             credentials = reader_function(**kwargs)
     64             logger.info('Using credentials from %s', display_name)
     65             if credentials:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/credentials/configrc.py in read_credentials_from_qiskitrc(filename)
     65         if 'verify' in single_credentials.keys():
     66             single_credentials['verify'] = bool(single_credentials['verify'])
---> 67         new_credentials = Credentials(**single_credentials)
     68         credentials_dict[new_credentials.unique_id()] = new_credentials
     69 

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

Is there any fundamental problem about the accounts?

Comment: Are you running this in the IBM Q Experience? If so, this is a known problem and the team are working to fix it as we speak!

Answer (score 2):

This was an error but it should now be fixed. If this happens again in future, the work around is to remove that line and use `IBMQ.enable_account(my_token)` instead.